# How to specify less than or equal to in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to write a logic as below to return the data.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Organization_code='MT_01'and start_date &lt; '2024-03-01'"> 
        <xsl:text>MT_06</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>                           
        <xsl:value-of select="$Organization_code"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Basically I am trying to pull organization codes, when organization code is `MT_01` and start date less than or equal to `2024-03-01`, return `MT_06` and in all other cases return the actual values of organization codes. But looks like less than or equal to is not working, i am getting actual values from organization code but not getting MT_06 when `Organization_code` and start date is less than `2024-03-01`. So I am looking for input how to specify less than or equal to in xslt because what I have tried above is not working.

Do let me know for any additional information if needed on this.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Please show a more complete XML and XSLT. I'm suspicious of your code because it uses both `Organization_code` as an element name and `$Organization_code` as a variable name; that could be correct, but it's a code smell.

Comment: The date comparison in your code is correct except that (a) it's comparing values as strings, not as dates, and (b) it's a less-than comparison, not a less-than-or-equal.

Comment: The other reason this might not be working is that you are unknowingly using an XSLT 1.0 processor, which will compare the two operands as numbers, and NaN<NaN is false.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the date comparison i have used is correct, the reason why it was not working since start date was defined as param, and i when i called param as $start date,it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
start_date le xs:date('2024-03-01')
```

or (if no schema is available to the processor):

```
xs:date(start_date) le xs:date('2024-03-01')
```

after declaring:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

See:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-comparisons
and:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-constructor-functions